# Export hasura data from cloud to docker?

Tags: docker, hasura

I'm trying to copy my hasura config from the cloud to a local docker build. I ran a hasura init through the CLI pointing at the cloud graphql engine (secret, etc).

Then ran a hasura metadata export, however that didn't seem to hav ean effect, the working directory was still empty.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have `config.yaml` setup with all the required keys. Otherwise you can also supply the args to hasura CLI

`hasura metadata export --endpoint <HASURA_ENDPOINT> --admin-secret <SECRET>`